# Error with Go proto imports when using bazel-gazelle

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, bazel, bazel-gazelle

I have a repository where I'm using gazelle and proto build rules. My repository is structured like this:

```
WORKSPACE
\ proto
  - user.proto
  - user_service.proto
  - BUILD
```

This is the `BUILD` file I have inside my proto folder:

```
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
load("@rules_proto_grpc//go:defs.bzl", "go_proto_library")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

proto_library(
    name = "user_proto",
    srcs = ["user.proto"],
    deps = [
        "@com_google_protobuf//:timestamp_proto",
    ],
)

proto_library(
    name = "user_service_proto",
    srcs = ["user_service.proto"],
    deps = [
        ":user_proto",
        "@com_google_protobuf//:empty_proto",
    ],
)

go_proto_library(
    name = "user_go_proto",
    importpath = "github.com/abcd/user/proto",
    protos = [":user_proto"],
)

go_proto_library(
    name = "user_service_go_proto",
    compilers = ["@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:go_grpc"],
    importpath = "github.com/abcd/userservice/proto",
    protos = [
        ":user_proto",
        ":user_service_proto",
    ],
)
```

This is my `user.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

package some_package;

option go_package = "github.com/abcd/user/proto";

message User {
 ...
}
```

And this is my `user_service.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "proto/user.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package some_package;

option go_package = "github.com/abcd/userservice/proto";

service UserService {
...
}
```

I then run `bazel build proto:all` and expect the go libraries to build successfully, but they do not.

Instead, I get an error stating that:

```
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
compilepkg: missing strict dependencies:
        /private/var/tmp/_bazel_mohammednadeem/2fc3c21998c67019e72a996be754820f/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/581/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/proto/user_service_go_proto_pb/github.com/abcd/userservice/proto/proto/user_service.pb.go: import of "github.com/abcd/user/proto"
No dependencies were provided.
Check that imports in Go sources match importpath attributes in deps.
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here. My importpaths look correct and I have the correct `option go_package` set in the proto file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I needed

```
   deps = [":user_go_proto"]
```

in the `user_service_go_proto` target.